# Print vertical and horizontal headers for multiplication table

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,7,6);
$array2 = array(2,3,1,0,5);
```

Then I tried to create `printTable` function to print multiplication table for arrays:

```
function printTable($array1, $array2) {
  echo "<table border=1px>";
  foreach ($array2 as $vert_head) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($array1 as $hor_head) {
      echo "<td>". ($vert_head * $hor_head) ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

And then print table:

```
$data = printTable($array1, $array2);
```

It works fine table is print. But how can I add horizontal and vertical header from arrays?

That how my table looks right now(just answers):

```
2 |  4 |  6 |  8 | 14 | 12 |
3 |  6 |  9 | 12 | 21 | 18 |
1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  7 |  6 | 
0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 35 | 30 |
```

How can I add headers:

```
|   | 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  7 |  6 |  
+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+
| 2 | 2 |  4 |  6 |  8 | 14 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 |  6 |  9 | 12 | 21 | 18 |
| 1 | 1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  7 |  6 | 
| 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
| 5 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 35 | 30 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included comments in place of modified code. It use and extra foreach loop to print heading.

```
<?php

$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,7,6);
$array2 = array(2,3,1,0,5);

function printTable($array1, $array2) {
  echo "<table border=1px>";

  /* In our table first cell is empty. So put a blank cell here. */
  echo '<tr><td></td>' ;

  /* Then print all headers in following cells */
  foreach($array1 as $head) {
    echo '<th>' . $head . '</th>' ;
  }
  /* close the first row */
  echo '</tr>';

  foreach ($array2 as $vert_head) {
    echo "<tr>";

    /* Before printing each row, print the left heading */
    echo '<td>' . $vert_head . '</td>' ;

    foreach ($array1 as $hor_head) {
      echo "<td>". ($vert_head * $hor_head) ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @CodyGray modified answer and thank you for the suggestion. I'm indeed making mistakes buy i'm surely trying to improve my questions and answers in every aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,7,6);
$array2 = array(2,3,1,0,5);
function printTable($array1, $array2) {
  echo "<table border=1px>";
  echo "<thead><tr><td></td>";
  echo "<th>" . implode("</th><th>", $array1) . "</th>";
  echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
  foreach ($array2 as $vert_head) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($array1 as $hor_head) {
      echo "<td>". ($vert_head * $hor_head) ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</tbody></table>";
}

printTable($array1, $array2);
```

It uses `implode()` to convert the `$array1` to **table headings**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this way also. This is the easiest way with your current code

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,7,6);
$array2 = array(2,3,1,0,5);
function printTable($array1, $array2) {
  echo "<table border='1px' style='text-align:right'>";
  echo '<tr><td></td>' ;
  foreach($array1 as $head) {
    echo '<td>' . $head . '</td>' ;
  }
  echo '</tr>';
  foreach ($array2 as $vert_head) {
    echo "<tr>";
     echo '<td>' . $vert_head . '</td>' ;
    foreach ($array1 as $hor_head) {
      echo "<td>". ($vert_head * $hor_head) ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
$data = printTable($array1, $array2);
```